# Add bottom-border to active link in menu wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

Hi my website is http://eeeonlinecourse.com/

I would like to style my menu bar using border-bottom property as follows:

```
header#top nav ul li a:hover{
    border-style: solid;
    border-bottom: thick solid #27CCC0;
}

header#top nav ul li a:active{
    border-style: solid;
    border-bottom: thick solid #27CCC0;
}
```

I have added these two lines into my child theme's stylesheet. However it does not seem to be working. Right now only the hover property is working fine. I have added an active selector after my hover selector but it is still not showing the bottom-border when the menu link is active. What should I add into my stylesheet?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Is it right?.Let's say when user click "Home", the bottom border will appear (under "Home" link).If so, just adds the css (your css) as shown in attached image. (.current_page_item) is the class added for CURRENT (selected) li. If home selected, then border-bottom will appear.

```
 header#top nav .sf-menu li.current_page_item > a,
 header#top nav .sf-menu li.current-menu-item > a,
 header#top nav .sf-menu li.current_page_item > a
 {
  border-style: solid;
  border-bottom: thick solid #27CCC0;
 }
```

If you want to see the live demo whether it works just like what you want, you can go to "inspect element" and click on 1(in my attached image).Then, add the css to 2(in my attached image).

And, Good Luck..Sorry if this is not the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your given code and reference site it seems that you have issue with active link only right?
If so than you can simply remove a.active because there is no active class applied to  link.
Instead use

> header#top nav ul li.current_page_item > a {
>     border-style: solid;
>     border-bottom: thick solid #27CCC0;
>    }

I hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving: current-menu-item is the active menu link.

```
li.current-menu-item a:active{ border-style: solid;
    border-bottom: thick solid #27CCC0; }
```

Hope this helps.